# Вернуться в приложение после завершения навигации

Tags: android, google-maps-api

1. Есть активность, из которой запускаю навигацию в стороннем приложении.
2. При почти достижении точки назначения хочу получать уведомление.
3. При нажатии на уведомление хочу возвращаться в мое приложение.

С 1 и 3 вроде бы проблем нет. С пунктом 2 не совсем понятно чем пользоваться? Создавать сервис, который будем отслеживать местоположение и отправлять пендинг интент? Но с 8 версии сервисы долго не живут, а навигация может длиться несколько часов.

Comment: пока телефон будет активен, то есть пока будет включено это приложение с навигацией, я уверен, что сервис будет жить (если телефон не китайский). В крайнем случае, сервис можно будет запустить как сервис переднего плана.

Answer (score 2):

Так как вы знаете локацию в которой вас надо разбудить, то вам могут помочь Geofences https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing. Т.е. вы регистрируете точку и вам прилетает Intent о достижении ее. На версии 8 есть ограничения, но как раз использование Geofence - это правильно поведение
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits

> Use elements of the Geofencing API, such as the GeofencingApi interface, which are optimized for minimizing power use.

Comment: так и сделал.
Вроде разобрался с Geofences  API.